# How to access the spring cloud gateway's WebClient or HTTPClient instance for configuring Observeabiltty?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

We are using [spring cloud gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) in our project and trying to add observerability to the system. We have custom transaction marking filters(interceptors) adhering to OTel(open telemetry) standards, which are passed to the `WebClient` & `RestTemplate` instances to generate telemetry data. However, since we are using the cloud gateway, the HttpClient instance(that is used for calling/routing downstream systems) is not accessible to the application layer to set the telemetry interceptors. Can anyone please help?

To illustrate, for any other micro service which uses `WebClient`, the telemetry(transaction marking interceptors) are configures as follows,

```
WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(...)
        ...
        .filter(CustomTransactionMarketingFilter.create())
        .build();
```

How can we achieve this in spring cloud gateway since the `HTTPClient`(that makes the downstream calls)  is not accessible to the application later?